# raspberry rosdep initialised, but still asking to initialise

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Trying to install ros desktop on raspberry pi.

I am at the resolving dependencies point and the command
sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
fails with ERROR: your rosdep installation has not been initialized yet. Please run: rosdep update

rosupdate runs fine, but the error still happens. Tried running rosdep init again, but get
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:Please delete if you want to re-initialize

tried deleting and re-initializing, but still getting the same error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54718/raspberry-rosdep-initialised,-but-still-asking-to-initialise/) by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1504 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got this to work by running sudo rosdep update.  Give it a try.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-02-15**:
You should not run `rosdep update` as root since it creates the database in your user home with root ownership.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-19**:
Without root access , I was not able to update the database.  Is there any reason it cannot be done without root access?